# "".split(" ") in SO's javascript

Tags: javascript

I've seen a lot of idioms, most of them clever and logical once explained. But while I was looking over SO's javascript to get some ideas about good interface design I saw the following line:

```
initTagRenderer("".split(" "), "".split(" "));
```

Which really threw me for a loop. Obviously, they initialize the tag renderer with two arrays containing exactly one null-string argument (or `[""]`, which `"".split(" ")` evaluates to). That part I understand (having done the same thing in my own code). But it seems like passing a literal would accomplish the same thing.

Is there some non-obvious reason for doing this that I'm failing to see as a newcomer (to js, not programming)?

*Also, I did try searching, and got lots of info on split() itself (which I already understand quite well), but not the idiom; Googling for double quotes is pretty fruitless.*

Edit: It was the obvious answer. This part of the code is dynamically generated, and is not usually populated on SO proper.

Comment: It's probably a value populated dynamically by the server, and in this case it's just populated with an empty string

Comment: I considered that, but I was unable to find anywhere on the site where that line differed. Although this could just be because my account is relatively pristine.

Comment: I didn't see it populated anywhere I checked either.

Comment: Source code here: http://cdn.sstatic.net/js/full.js?v=f1c33d3703f2 Something like `function initTagRenderer(f,c){window.tagRenderer||(window.tagRendererRaw=function(b,g){var g=g||"",e="";g||(f&&-1<$.inArray(b,f)?e=" required-tag":c&&-1<$.inArray(b,c)&&(e=" moderator-tag"));return"<a class='post-tag"+e+"' href='"+g+"/questions/tagged/"+encodeURIComponent(b)+"' title=\"show questions tagged '"+b+"'\" rel='tag'>"+b+"</a>"},window.tagRenderer=function(b,c){return $(tagRendererRaw(b,c))})}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is probably server-side code that dynamically populates those arguments to look something like this:

```
initTagRenderer("javascript php".split(" "), "ruby lisp".split(" "));
```

What that function does, I have no idea. But it must require an array of tag names, and it's easier to generate a space-delimited list rather than a JS array literal.

### Edit

After some heroic investigating, it appears that `initTagRenderer` does indeed nicely format question tags. Tags that match a name in the first parameter are given a `required-tag` class, and tags that match the second parameter are given a `moderator-tag` class.

According to Madmartigan, it's used on meta:

```
initTagRenderer(
     "bug feature-request discussion support".split(" "),
     "faq status-completed status-declined status-bydesign status-norepro status-reproduced status-planned status-deferred status-review featured community-ads".split(" ")
);
```

[**View example**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125880/would-you-like-to-have-responses-to-your-questions-sent-to-you-via-email-link)

---

Relevant (but minified) line of full.js:

```
function initTagRenderer(f,c){window.tagRenderer||(window.tagRendererRaw=function(b,g){var g=g||"",e="";g||(f&&-1<$.inArray(b,f)?e=" required-tag":c&&-1<$.inArray(b,c)&&(e=" moderator-tag"));return"<a class='post-tag"+e+"' href='"+g+"/questions/tagged/"+encodeURIComponent(b)+"' title=\"show questions tagged '"+b+"'\" rel='tag'>"+b+"</a>"},window.tagRenderer=function(b,c){return $(tagRendererRaw(b,c))})}
```

Comment: I think this renders tags for questions, e.g. 'javascript' or 'stackoverflow.com'

Comment: It's used on meta for required and mod-only tags (the red ones): `initTagRenderer("bug feature-request discussion support".split(" "), "faq status-completed status-declined status-bydesign status-norepro status-reproduced status-planned status-deferred status-review featured community-ads".split(" "));`

Comment: @bkconrad, not idiotic at all! You were right — no one would ever hand-code something like that. Server-side code creates some client-side anomalies, since you can't examine it.